# Android - Navigation component with bottom tabs - Navigating from TabA to TabB programmatically

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

### Context

The app operates on a single activity, with bottom tab navigation within it.

I have a button from "Home" tab, that when clicked, leads to TabB with arguments (to be used for rendering).

### Code

*Please assume the navigation component is correctly setup, and is working in all cases except for this one*.

Main nav file `nav_main.xml` looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@+id/menu_home">
    
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_navigate_to_TabB"
        app:destination="@id/menu_tabB"/>

    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_home" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_tabB" />
</navigation>
```

Navigation for the Home tab looks like `nav_home.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/menu_home"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.home.HomeFragment" />

</navigation>
```

Navigation for TabB looks like `nav_tabB.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/menu_tabB"
    app:startDestination="@id/tabBFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/tabBFragment"
        android:name="com.example.RootTabBFragment">
        // Some argument tags
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I use the following snippet to navigate from "Home" to TabB with arguments

```kotlin
// If TabB's backstack is done for, it should pop up to start destination.
val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(
        navController.graph.findStartDestination().id,
        inclusive = false,
        saveState = true
).build()
fragment.findNavController()
        .navigate(
                resId = R.id.action_navigate_to_TabB,
                args = // Some args,
                navOptions = navOptions
        )
```

As you can see from above, the action is defined as a global action in main nav graph XML.

```xml
<action
        android:id="@+id/action_navigate_to_TabB"
        app:destination="@id/menu_tab_B" />
```

Also tried to make this action localised only to the "Home" navigation XML, but that didn't work.

### Issue

What happens with this snippet is:

- Creates a new root fragment for TabB (expected).
- Creates a new VM for it instead of re-using the old VM (unexpected).
  *The old VM is not destroyed/cleared yet*
- Then afterwards, when the user switches between tabs and back to TabB, the nav component revives the old VM not the new one, showing an inconsistent and out-of-date state.

Maybe I'm doing this wrong from the very start? maybe I'm missing a step?

All sorts of help is much appreciated!

Comment: could you show all fragment code and all navigation resource code?

Comment: You still didn't add full fragment code. Add HomeFragment full code and RootTabBFragment full code

Comment: There is nothing special about those two fragment's code that would be relevant to navigating in and out of them :))
I think what's relevant here is the snippet used to navigate from Home to TabB.